# Power BI Report Viewing on Local Repository?

Tags: azure, powerbi

Is it possible to have Power BI Reports in a VMs local repository in Azure? How about the report access being on the VM's local repository?

Lets say our VM's local address in Azure is 10.0.2.1.

When distributing a Power BI dashboard or report the link that is being sent or accessed is for example: https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=asubisdiucibsdibciasb:

This means the viewing of the Power BI report is not on the Azure VM local repository

We want it so that we can view these reports on our Azure VM Local repository like so https://10.0.2.1:8080/powerbi/usagereports/report1

In this way we are not going through Powerbi.com to view the reports but just our own links/repositories.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? What's wrong with using the Power BI Service? That will help us answer the question better.

Comment: @GregGalloway, This is more flexible on our end. I am just wondering if this is possible. Nothing is wrong with Power BI Service, an alternative as above is preferred. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power BI reports can be deployed to the Power BI Service (app.powerbi.com) or Power BI Embedded (an Azure service that does not run on a VM). With either of those options you can use REST APIs to embed the reports in a website that's running on a VM (but that's still possibly not what you want because it is still reaching out to an external Power BI service to render the report).

I would suggest you look at the new [Preview of Power BI reports in Reporting Services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2017/01/17/power-bi-reports-in-sql-server-reporting-services-january-2017-technical-preview-now-available/) that will ship with SQL Server vNext. It may do what you want.